# Are there compiler directives for specifying the type of adder synthesized?

Tags: verilog, fpga, system-verilog, vlsi

I haven't had any luck finding this on Google, so here goes:

Has anyone heard of a design compiler directive to specify which type of adder is synthesized? I'm looking for something that would work somewhat like this:

```
logic [7:0] a, b, c, d, e, f;

/* ... */

// synopsys use_carry_look_ahead
assign c = a + b;

// synopsys use_carry_select
assign f = d + e;
```

FWIW, I'm writing with SystemVerilog and using the Synopsys DC compiler, but if anyone has heard of directives to accomplish this for other compilers, I am all ears.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if it's exactly what you're looking for, but there's a lot of adder options in `set_dp_smartgen_options`

```
   status set_dp_smartgen_options
          [-all_options auto | true | false | default]
          [-booth_encoding auto | true | false]
          [-booth_radix8 auto | true | false]
          [-booth_mux_based auto | true | false]
          [-booth_cell auto | true | false]
          [-mult_nand_based auto | true | false]
          [-inv_out_adder_cell auto | true | false]
          [-4to2_compressor_cell auto | true | false]
          [-adder_radix auto | 2 | 3 | 4]
          [-ling_adder auto | true | false]
          [-hybrid_adder auto | true | false]
          [-carry_select_adder_cell auto | true | false]
          [-cond_sum_adder auto | true | false]
          [-sklansky_adder auto | true | false]
          [-brent_kung_adder auto | true | false]
          [-bounded_fanout_adder auto | true | false]
          [-mux_based auto | true | false]
          [-inv_adder_cell auto | true | false]
          [-sop2pos_transformation auto | true | false]
          [-tp_opt_tree auto | true | false]
          [-tp_oper_sel auto | true | false]
          [-smart_compare auto | true | false]
          [-optimize_for default | area | speed | area,speed]
          [-power_effort off | auto | medium | high]
          [-hierarchy]
          [design or cell list]
          [-retime design_list]
          [-retime_clk_period period_value]
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not know of a Synopsys pragma to select a specfic implementation, but the DesignWare documentation claims you can force Design Compiler to use one of the available architectures.